# multi value SQL query with OR

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to query across several normalized tables to bring back a range of data. It works fine until I put "OR" in the difficulty_level and route_level with another variable to look for, at that point the loading message pops up in MAMP and it just stays like that. Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
h.hike_name, 
h.length_miles, 
h.elevation_gain_feet, 
h.nearest_city, 
h.geo_location, 
d.difficulty_name, 
r.route_name 
FROM 
`park_tbl` p, 
`hike_tbl` h, 
`park-hike_rtbl` ph, 
`difficulty_tbl` d, 
`hike-difficulty_rtbl` hd, 
`route_tbl` r, 
`hike-route_rtbl` hr  
WHERE p.park_name = 'Acadia National Park' 
AND d.difficulty_level = 1 or 2
AND r.route_level = 1 or 2
AND p.park_id = ph.park_id 
AND h.hike_id = ph.hike_id 
AND h.hike_id = hd.hike_id 
AND d.difficulty_id =hd.difficulty_id
AND h.hike_id = hr.hike_id 
AND r.route_id = hr.route_id
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. please let me know if any other information would be helpful. it is a very large program with both SQL and Python, so I don't want to try to post it all.

NEW INFO:

OK, so in response to the comment below, thank you! That worked in the SQL query in MAMP, but did not work for me in python, I think I am getting close though.

I have checkbuttons in a tkinter GUI. These are fed into different statements to give me data back. it ranges from 1-5(difficulty) and 1-3(route). If the box is checked it gives back the value, if not it gives back a "0". I took care of that by adding a column in the sql tables called level, and added a placeholder with the value of "0". I get back a iteration of this below depending on the statement.

```
(1,2,3,4,5) or (0,0,0,4,5) etc difficulty level.
(1,2,3) or (1,2,0) etc route level
```

This is the code I am using now for the python SQL, but it gives me back a database error. it seems like it should work if this works in MAMP.

```
sql = "SELECT " \
          "h.hike_name, " \
          "h.length_miles, " \
          "h.elevation_gain_feet, " \
          "h.nearest_city, " \
          "h.geo_location, " \
          "d.difficulty_name, " \
          "r.route_name " \
          "FROM " \
          "`park_tbl` p, " \
          "`hike_tbl` h, " \
          "`park-hike_rtbl` ph, " \
          "`difficulty_tbl` d, " \
          "`hike-difficulty_rtbl` hd, " \
          "`route_tbl` r, " \
          "`hike-route_rtbl` hr " \
          "WHERE " \
          "p.park_name = %s " \
          "AND (d.difficulty_level = %s " \
          "OR d.difficulty_level = %s " \
          "OR d.difficulty_level = %s " \
          "OR d.difficulty_level = %s " \
          "OR d.difficulty_level = %s) " \
          "AND (r.route_level = %s " \
          "OR r.route_level = %s " \
          "OR r.route_level =  %s) " \
          "AND p.park_id = ph.park_id " \
          "AND h.hike_id = ph.hike_id " \
          "AND h.hike_id = hd.hike_id " \
          "AND d.difficulty_id =hd.difficulty_id" \
          "AND h.hike_id = hr.hike_id " \
          "AND r.route_id = hr.route_id"
```

I'm not sure, but it must be something with Python. any thoughts?

New INFO:
This is the function I am using to get the data that is fed into the SQL query.

```
def search_hikes():  #=====database error=======#
try:
    park = selected_park.get()
    difficulty = diffvar1.get(), diffvar2.get(), diffvar3.get(), diffvar4.get(), diffvar5.get()
    route = rtvar1.get(), rtvar2.get(), rtvar3.get()
    # state = selected_state.get()#- don't need for query- only need the park name for park-hike_rtbl
    print(park, difficulty, route)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    messagebox.showinfo("Tkinter", "Select State, Park, Difficulty, and Route types.")
    raise Exception

try:
    rows_p, num_rows_p = search_parks_in_dbs(park, difficulty, route)
except Exception as e:
    messagebox.showinfo("Tkinter", "Database error")  #error here?
    exit()

if num_rows_p == 0:
    messagebox.showinfo("Database Error", "No results")

else:
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(form)
    newWindow.title("Search Results")
    newWindow.geometry("1200x800")

    table = ttk.Treeview(newWindow, columns=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), height=80, show="headings")

    table.heading(1, text="Hike Name")
    table.heading(2, text="Length(Mi)")
    table.heading(3, text="Elevation Gain(ft)")
    table.heading(4, text="Difficulty")
    table.heading(5, text="Nearest City")
    table.heading(6, text="Location")
    table.heading(7, text="Route Type")

    table.column(1, width=300)
    table.column(2, width=80)
    table.column(3, width=80)
    table.column(4, width=80)
    table.column(5, width=150)
    table.column(6, width=130)
    table.column(7, width=130)

    table.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=7, padx=15, pady=15)

    for row in rows_p:
        table.insert('', 'end', values=(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]))


def search_parks_in_dbs(hikes, difficulty, route):
    try:
        con = open_database()
    except Exception:
        messagebox.showinfo("Database connection error")
        exit()

messagebox.showinfo("Connected to Database", "DB Connection OK")

try:
    sql = "SELECT " \
          "h.hike_name, " \
          "h.length_miles, " \
          "h.elevation_gain_feet, " \
          "h.nearest_city, " \
          "h.geo_location, " \
          "d.difficulty_name, " \
          "r.route_name " \
          "FROM " \
          "`park_tbl` p, " \
          "`hike_tbl` h, " \
          "`park-hike_rtbl` ph, " \
          "`difficulty_tbl` d, " \
          "`hike-difficulty_rtbl` hd, " \
          "`route_tbl` r, " \
          "`hike-route_rtbl` hr " \
          "WHERE " \
          "p.park_name = %s " \
          "AND d.difficulty_level IN (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) " \
          "AND r.route_level IN (%s,%s,%s) " \
          "AND p.park_id = ph.park_id " \
          "AND h.hike_id = ph.hike_id " \
          "AND h.hike_id = hd.hike_id " \
          "AND d.difficulty_id = hd.difficulty_id" \
          "AND h.hike_id = hr.hike_id " \
          "AND r.route_id = hr.route_id"

    vals = (hikes, difficulty, route)
    print(sql)
    num_of_rows, rows = query_database(con, sql, vals)
except DatabaseError:
    messagebox.showinfo("Error querying the database")

return rows, num_of_rows
```

And this if the code for the Checkbuttons, any suggestions would be great, I am so close to getting this working. these functions are so i can view the output.

```
    # ==Difficulty level checkboxes==
def diff_states():
    diffvars = diffvar1.get(), diffvar2.get(), diffvar3.get(), diffvar4.get(), diffvar5.get()
    print("easiest: %d,\nmoderate: %d,\nmoderatly strenuous: %d,\nstrenuous: %d,\nvery strenuous: %d" % (
    diffvar1.get(), diffvar2.get(), diffvar3.get(), diffvar4.get(), diffvar5.get()))
    print(diffvar1.get(), diffvar2.get(), diffvar3.get(), diffvar4.get(), diffvar5.get())
    print(diffvars)
    return diffvars


# check buttons
diffvar1 = IntVar()
diff1 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="easiest", variable=diffvar1, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=1, offvalue=None)
selected_diff = diff1
diffvar2 = IntVar()
diff2 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="Moderate", variable=diffvar2, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=2, offvalue=None)
diffvar3 = IntVar()
diff3 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="Moderately Strenuous", variable=diffvar3, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=3, offvalue=None)
diffvar4 = IntVar()
diff4 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="Strenuous", variable=diffvar4, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=4, offvalue=None)
diffvar5 = IntVar()
diff5 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="Very Strenuous", variable=diffvar5, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=5, offvalue=None)


quit = Button(tab3, text='Quit', width=5, bg="black", fg='white', command=tab3.quit)
showdiff = Button(tab3, text='Show', width=5, bg="white", fg='black', command=diff_states)

showdiff.grid(row=8, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
quit.grid(row=16, column=2, sticky=NW, pady=4)


# route type checkbuttons
def rt_states():
    rtvars = rtvar1.get(), rtvar2.get(), rtvar3.get()
    print("loop: %d,\nout and back: %d,\npoint to point: %d" % (rtvar1.get(), rtvar2.get(), rtvar3.get()))
    print(rtvar1.get(), rtvar2.get(), rtvar3.get())
    print(rtvars)
    return rtvars


rtvar1 = IntVar()
rt1 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="loop", variable=rtvar1, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
rtvar2 = IntVar()
rt2 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="out and back", variable=rtvar2, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=2, offvalue=0)
rtvar3 = IntVar()
rt3 = Checkbutton(tab3, text="point to point", variable=rtvar3, font=("bold", 12), onvalue=3, offvalue=0)


showrt = Button(tab3, text='Show', width=5, bg="white", fg='black', command=rt_states)
showrt.grid(row=14, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4)
```

Comment: SQL requires more verbosity than that: `AND d.difficulty_level = 1 or d.difficulty_level = 2`. Also, the precedence of `OR` is such that you should use parentheses around anything involving it: `AND (d.difficulty_level = 1 or d.difficulty_level = 2)`.

Comment: You can reduce a lot of this with `AND d.difficulty_level IN (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)` and `AND r.route_level IN (%s,%s,%s)`.

Comment: So, for your upper example, `AND d.difficulty_level IN (1,2) AND r.route_level IN (1,2)`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that shortened it up for sure, and worked fine in MAMP, but not in Python, so it must be something with how the data is structured. I would post the program, but it is huge. I will post the statement I am using to get the data from the checkbuttons.

Comment: You have to give it one long list, not nested lists.    `vals = (hikes,) + difficulty + route` should do it.  `difficulty` and `route` are already tuples, so we just convert `hikes` to a tuple and combine them.  But don't you really want `park`?

Comment: So, the park is determined by 2 comboboxes. the first is the state, and the second is a dependent combobox that only lists the parks in the selected state. TI used a dictionary in python because it was easier, and looked better. so even though all of that info is in my database, I only need to query on the park to pull up all of the hikes in that park, then narrow it down with the difficulty level and route type. So I will try just what you suggest and see if it works.

Comment: Use @username to reply to someone

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.